# How to use SaveAs in c# inorder to read and convert PDF to text?

Tags: c#, vba

I have been converting VBA code to C# and I'm stuck with this line. Can anyone guide me on how to write the equivalent code in C#.

How do I use `SaveAs` in C#?

```
lResult = oJSO.SaveAs(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Inputs\CAR.txt", "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text")
```

Comment: what kind of object is oJSO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are looking for this

```
var lResult = oJSO.SaveAs(ThisWorkbook.Path + "\\Inputs\\CAR.txt", "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text");
```

Comment: SaveAs and ThisWorkbook is not identified. Any reference or dll to be added??

Comment: @Kat Which references were you using in the working VBA code? Also aren't Workbooks related to Excel?

Comment: Hope [Export to Text in C# using SDK 9](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/302212) might help you more

Comment: Hey that was of a great help :) Now only thing I have to see is Conversion of text to my desired format.